# How to show or hide a graph line in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

How do we toggle a line on and off (hide or show) in Bokeh again ? The example figure below does not update.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("toggle_lines.html")

### Main plot
plot = figure()

# Dummy data for testing
x = list(range(25))
y0 = [ 3**a for a in x]

l0 = plot.line(x, y0, color='blue')
l0.visible = False

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["l0"], active=[1])

checkbox.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(l0=l0), code="""l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;"""))

layout = row(checkbox, plot)
show(layout)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main things:

1. your `active` argument should either be `[0]` indicating that the 0th checkbutton in the Group should be active, or should not be supplied, indicating that the default state of all checkboxes should be inactive. By indicating `[1]` you're telling bokeh there's actually 2 checkboxes and 1 of them is active which leads to errors.
2. You'll need to pass your checkbox object into the javascript code via the `args` in your callback (you've already done this with the line, just need to include the checkbox group as well.

This code worked for me:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("toggle_lines.html")

### Main plot
plot = figure(x_range=(0, 25))

# Dummy data for testing
x = list(range(25))
y0 = [ 3**a for a in x]

l0 = plot.line(x, y0, color='blue')
l0.visible = False

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["l0"])

checkbox.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(l0=l0, checkbox=checkbox), code="""l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;"""))

layout = row(checkbox, plot)
show(layout)
```